# Piping input streams in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, inputstream

The main idea behind Java InputStreams is that once it is consumed, you cannot re-read that data. Generally, this condition is good enough for most cases.

However, it so happens that there are cases when we may want to process some data multiple times in different ways. For example, imagine I am writing a git-like tool. Thus I want to first generate the hash of the data, then store the data, and possibly do some more operations on the same data (e.g. replicating the data somewhere else or whatever).

I like to think of this process as shown in the diagram below:

```
data --> hash() --> save() --> replicate() --> ...
          |           |            |
          ▼           ▼            ▼
        aa231e      /A/aa231e    http://example.org/A/aa231e
```

**UPDATE Start**

Clearly as soon as the first few bytes are used for the hash() function, we could reuse them for the save() function too, while the hash function keeps going. Thus parallelising hash(), save(), replicate(), etc.

**UPDATE End**

Now, I was wondering:

1. Is it possible to achieve this using Java? I have some vague ideas that involve implementing a custom InputStream and use a shared buffer, but I am really not sure this is the right way of doing it.
2. If the answer to (1) is yes, how? If it is a no, what would you suggest me to do?
3. Are there any available libraries/framework that I could use to achieve this type of piping?

I would also like to understand what the pros and cons of any possible solutions are and why.

ps. I am not looking for a solution that opens-consumes-closes and re-opens the same stream again and again.

Comment: Look at [BufferInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html), particularly at the mark and reset methods. Also look at PushbackInputStream.

Comment: That is very much not the 'main idea behind InputStream'. look at the `mark` and `reset` methods which are defined on `InputStream` itself.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thank you. I update my answer with a bit more of description. I think I can see how using mark/reset can help. However, could that work for large amounts of data too? In the updated version of the question, I added that it would be great to parallelize the process. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a good question for SO which deals with mostly specific programming questions (i.e. ones that have code attached). There are better ones, perhaps SE. That said, you should be thinking about your design in general, not how to jam it all into the InputStream abstraction. Typically, if you have a data source of some sort, you can have it produce new InputStreams so you can use them as intended - sequential data access and composability. If all you want is a hash, you can simply add a 'compute hash' method to your source, no need for InputStreams.